# Test if object file is OS independent

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile

I have several object files (.o) ,without source code, for a vxWorks project.

How can I test if they are OS independent or not?

I try to use them for a Linux project.
They should include openGL stuff.

edit:

I have a Graphic board with a S3 on it.
 There is a driver available for it, but just for vxWorks.
 I found a startup script for vxWorks. In this several Objekt files will be loaded.

e.g this

```
ld 1,0,"lib/libGL.o"        
ld 1,0,"lib/libGLU.o"
```

And I think they are independent from the OS.But I'm not sure.
 Because I try to use this board with Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link them against a `main()` function. If you get no errors, then they don't use OS specific functions.

**[EDIT]** Object files are linked, not included. You need to write a `main()` function which calls code in the `.o` files (check the OpenGL documentation for the names).

Now you can compile this with:

```
 cc -c -o main.o main.c
 cc -o main main.o lib/libGL.o lib/libGLU.o
```

Comment: First thanks for the Answer. I had the same idea, but to be honest I actually don't know how to do that exactly. Can you give me a short example?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. That makes it hard to give specific advice. Unless you can tell me more details about the object files, I can't help you. Interesting questions are: What do you really mean by "OS independent"? Where did you find these files? Why do you think you can use them? Do you have any documentation?

Comment: I edit the question. How is the mechanism to include a object file without knowing the header name?